# QtOpenCL won't build for Mac

Tags: macos, qt, opencl

I'm trying to get OpenCL, Qt, and my Mac (OS 10.9.5, 15" Macbook Pro, early 2011) to all play nice with each other at once. I started by dimly following the instructions [on the QtOpenCL snapshot site](http://doc.qt.digia.com/opencl-snapshot/building.html), but was met early on with

```
Could not detect an OpenCL implementation ... aborting
```

I did some digging, and apparently, all Macs come pre-loaded with OpenCL since, like, 2007, and I never tried to get rid of anything so deep in the system, so I knew that couldn't be right. After about 7 more hours of googling, I found [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-48584.html), after which I commented out some test code in ./configure (per the thread). It no longer pretends there's no OpenCL framework, but instead:

```
$ ./configure -qmake /usr/bin/qmake

This is the QtOpenCL configuration utility.

Qt version ............. 4.8.6
qmake .................. /usr/bin/qmake
OpenCL 1.0 ............. no
OpenCL 1.1 ............. no
OpenCL/OpenGL interop .. no
Extra QMAKE_CXXFLAGS ...
Extra INCLUDEPATH ......
Extra LIBS ............. -framework OpenCL

WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/src/opencl/QtOpenCL.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/src/openclgl/QtOpenCLGL.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/demos/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/demos/bezierpatch/bezierpatch.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/util/clinfo/clinfo.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/util/mkblurtable/mkblurtable.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/examples/opencl/vectoradd/vectoradd.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/examples/opencl/blur/blur.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/examples/opencl/pathdrawing/pathdrawing.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/examples/opencl/imagedrawing/imagedrawing.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/examples/opencl/colorize/colorize.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/tests/auto/qcl/tst_qcl.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/tests/benchmarks/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.xcodeproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) '~/qt-labs-opencl/tests/benchmarks/overhead/overhead.xcodeproj'
QtOpenCL has been configured.  Run '/usr/bin/make' to build.
```

Now, this shouldn't be a problem, except there's no makefile:

```
$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Seriously:

```
$ls
LGPL_EXCEPTION.txt      README              doc                
opencl.xcodeproj
LICENSE.FDL         config.tests            examples            src
LICENSE.LGPL            configure           opencl.pro          tests
LICENSE.PREVIEW.COMMERCIAL  demos               opencl.pro.user                  
util
```

I've looked into all of the .pro files in the tree, starting with opencl.pro, and none of them seem to contain .xcodeproj dependencies, although there does seem to be a file missing from the package (it's required for the build, but not part of the download). Anyone else get this problem/know of a workaround?

Edit: Solution, for posterity: Turns out all I had to do was add `OpenCl.framework` (usually located in `/System/Library/Frameworks`) as a library in Qt Creator, but that's just for getting openCL to work with Qt. Still no dice on QtOpenCL, but then again, all you *really* need is the openCL library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, **QtOpenCL** is abandoned. I recommend writing to the OpenCL API (if you like C) or use the cl.hpp C++ wrapper (if you like C++) (it's available from the Khronos website).

You can still use Qt for everything else it provides. They can work together.

Comment: cl.hpp has some missing functionality, like events (they are similar to the C version using pointers instead of reference, not OO friendly), but overall is much easier than plain C therefore recommended.